# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression, Oledb UPDATE Statement

Tags: c#, oledb, oledbcommand

I'm a beginner at c# and I've tried looking through many posts to try and resolve my problem but I haven't had any luck, so I thought I may as well create a post to ask for your help. Basically,I'm trying to update an excel file with some extra info, but the problem is every-time I run the source code I keep getting this error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Wireless Stereo Headphone (TAK)      (damaged)'.

I've tried a lot of ways to fix it including using an INSERT statement instead of the UPDATE statement but nothing seems to work.

Thanks again for the Help =).

```
int m_intRecipientESMID = Convert.ToInt32(m_recipientESMID);

//Converting Row integer to string
string m_excelRowCoordinateLoanItemTrackerStr = m_excelRowCoordinateLoanItemTracker.ToString();

//Creating a connection directory to access the Excel "LoanItemTracker" file
string m_pathSourceExcelLoanItemTrackerNOHDR = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + textBoxExcelLoanItemTrackerLocation.Text + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0; HDR=NO;ImportMixedTypes=Text;TypeGuessRows=0""";
OleDbConnection m_pathConnectionExcelLoanItemTrackerNOHDR = new OleDbConnection(m_pathSourceExcelLoanItemTrackerNOHDR);

m_pathConnectionExcelLoanItemTrackerNOHDR.Open();   //Open Excel File LoanItemTracker.xlsx to conduct Write/Update process

string m_scannedItemName2 = "Wireless Stereo Headphone (TAK)      (damaged)";

// write the loaned item name into the Excel Spread sheet "LoanItemTracker.xls"
string m_excelRowColumnLoanItemNameCoord = String.Concat(m_excelColumnCoordinateLoanItemNameLoanItemTracker, m_excelRowCoordinateLoanItemTrackerStr);
string m_LoanItemNameWriteCommand = String.Format("UPDATE [Sheet1${0}:{0}] SET F1={1}", m_excelRowColumnLoanItemNameCoord, m_scannedItemName2);
OleDbCommand m_LoanItemTrackerCommandWrite = new OleDbCommand(m_LoanItemNameWriteCommand, m_pathConnectionExcelLoanItemTrackerNOHDR);

m_LoanItemTrackerCommandWrite.ExecuteNonQuery();

m_pathConnectionExcelLoanItemTrackerNOHDR.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put quotes around the text:

```
String.Format("UPDATE [Sheet1${0}:{0}] SET F1='{1}'", m_excelRowColumnLoanItemNameCoord, m_scannedItemName2);
```

I put them before and after `{1}`. Also, it is preferred to use parameterized queries. You won't need quotes then too.

Answer (score 0):

check it : `UPDATE [Sheet1${0}:{0}] SET F1='{1}'` maybe you forgot quotes.