# IF A BLANK SPACE IS PRESENT IN THE COLUMN HEADING .....AND/OR operator not working in sql statement in c# .net for modifying an excel sheet

Tags: c#, sql, .net, excel, oledb

A run time error is occurring if i use and/or statements in the sql statements..Pls help me solve the problem

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand;
myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
string sql = null;
MessageBox.Show("Opening " + selectedPath);
MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + rootPath+"FacultyDutiesEnd.xls" + "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
MyConnection.Open();
myCommand.Connection = MyConnection;
sql = "Update [Sheet1$] set A1 = '\u221A',A2 = '\u221A',B1 = '\u221A',B2 = '\u221A',C1 = '\u221A',C2 = '\u221A',D1 = '\u221A',D2 = '\u221A',E1 = '\u221A',E2 = '\u221A',F1 = '\u221A',F2 = '\u221A',G1 = '\u221A',G2 = '\u221A'";
myCommand.CommandText = sql;
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
sql = "Update [Sheet1$] set A1 = 'a' where Designation = 'Prof(senior)'  and (Faculty Name = 'bob') ";// this line is not being executed unless the    and (Faculty Name = 'bob')    is removed
myCommand.CommandText = sql;
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

error is too long ,,begins with
System.data.oledb.oledbException(0x80040E14):Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Designation = 'Prof' and Name = 'bob'........

And if
and Faculty Name = 'bob'     is replaced with
and A2= '\u221A'    is used it is working

Update

if I keep blank space between design ation  ...even it is not working ...So is there any way where the column heading has a blank space and sql statement will be executed?

Comment: Why do you use it like `(Name = 'bob')`? Why not just `Name = 'bob'`? Are you sure your `Name` column is a character typed?

Comment: can you please post the error message?

Comment: No,it is alpha numeric as it is an excel file column.Even the designation column is alphanumeric.

Comment: check this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23855163/syntax-error-missing-operator-in-query-expression-oledb-update-statement

perhaps it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the problem is the space in the name of your `Faculty Name` column and that this has nothing to do with the use of `AND` or `OR`. Please try:

```
sql = "Update [Sheet1$] set A1 = 'a' " +
      "where Designation = 'Prof(senior)' and [Faculty Name] = 'bob'";
```

Comment: Thanx JLRISHE and sorry everyone for ambiguous question...